# How do I add a class to appended element using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add 'list-group-item' class while appending an element with jquery?

After appending an `<li>` to the `<ul id="todoList">`, the class property is not working as i expected.

```
  $("#todoList").append($('<li>', {
    text: $('#todoInput').val(),

    class: $('list-group-item') // this is not working
  }));
```

Comment: Replace `class: $('list-group-item')` with `class: 'list-group-item'`. Using `$()` is a selector.

Comment: we should pass the class name as `class: 'list-group-item'`. `$()` will return the jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
$("#todoAddBtn").on("click", function() {
  $("#todoList").append($('<li>', {
    text: $('#todoInput').val(),
    class: 'list-group-item' // <-- Class name should be an string
  }));
  $('#todoInput').val(''); // Clear input..
});
```

```css
.list-group-item {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="todoList"></ul>
<input id="todoInput">
<button id="todoAddBtn">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `class: $('list-group-item')`, you're basically creating an object that you add to the `class`. You just want a string that is the class-name, and not an object. All you need is `class: 'list-group-item'`.

```
$("#todoAddBtn").on("click", function() {
  $("#todoList").append($('<li>', {
    text: $('#todoInput').val(),
    class: 'list-group-item'
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this 'list-group-item' then change it to

```
class: 'list-group-item'
```